# Create binary mask from two segmentation lines in Python

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I have two segmentation lines stored in variables seg1 (bottom line in image) and seg2 (upper line in image) as 1-d numpy arrays. I'm trying to create an image where is black everywhere except the region inside those two lines -> white. What I am doing is the following which does not work:

```
binaryim = np.zeros_like(im)
for col in range(0, im.shape[1]):
    for row in range(0, im.shape[0]):
        if row < seg1[col] or row > seg2[col]: 
            binaryim[row][col] = 0
        else:
            binaryim[row][col] = 255
```

Any ideas? Everything inside those lines should be one and everything outside should be zero.

[image: Seg2 and seg1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer I could think of and it works was the following:
Given im the image, curve1, curve2 the curves:

```
rows, cols = np.indices(im.shape)
mask0=(rows < curve1) & (rows > curve2)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.imshow(mask0,origin='lower',cmap='gray')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.arange` to mask rows and `cmap='gray'` to plot white and black:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

im=np.zeros((100,100)) + 0
r1, r2 = 31,41

rows = np.arange(im.shape[0])
m1 = np.logical_and(rows > r1, rows < r2)
im[rows[m1], :] = 255
plt.imshow(im, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

To work on a pixel level, get the row and column indices from `np.indices`:

```
def line_func(col, s, e):
    return (s + (e - s) * col / im.shape[1]).astype(np.int)

r1, r2 = [20, 25], [30, 35]
rows, cols = np.indices(im.shape)
m1 = np.logical_and(rows > line_func(cols, *r1),
                    rows < line_func(cols, *r2))
im+= 255 * (m1)
plt.imshow(im, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Comment: will this work if r1 and r2 are 1d arrays (so not straight lines)?

Comment: can we modify this snippet to work on a pixel level? The lines are not necessarily straight segments but can be contours.

Comment: Yes, I added a snippet to do lines. Hopefully you get the idea on how to filter rows and column values using `np.indices`. If you can't, pass a sample of your curves and I'll explain it

Comment: You are defining the lines with a start and end point, while in my case the lines are curves and thus consist of many points. Shouldn't the function be different?

Comment: yes, I illustrated the example with lines as it is much easier to see. You can replace it with any function as long as it is index based. A line is a function of the index, with start and end as arguments. Remember indices increase down, so you need `np.logical_and(rows > top_function(cols,..), rows < bot_function(cols,...))`

Comment: I created a simpler solution as can be seen in my post